# Replace the last value of each row by the penultimate

Tags: python, numpy, replace, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that looks like this:
[image]

And I need to replace the last (non-empty) value of each row by the value before it.

```
for row in cohort_pivot2.iterrows():
   a=[i for i in row[1].values if i][-1]
   b=[i for i in row[1].values if i][-2]
```

But I can't think of any way to do the substitution.

I have not added the steps to replicate the pivot table because it's generated from confidential information and it's a process that would take up a lot of space, but if necessary I'd generate dummy data and replicate the process.

I would greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `apply` which converts each row to a list and then convert it back to a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,None],
            [10,20,None,None],
            [100,None,None,None]]).fillna('')
```

#### using list addition

```
ll = df.apply(lambda x: list(x)[:list(x).index('')-1] +  [list(x)[list(x).index('')-2]] + ['']*(length - list(x).index('')), 1)
```

#### using list comprehension

```
ll = df.apply(lambda x: [el if idx != list(x).index('') -1 else list(x)[list(x).index('') -2]  for idx, el in enumerate(list(x))], 1)
```

results in

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(ll)
#    0   1   2   3
# 0  1   2   2  
# 1  10  10     
# 2
```

Please note that the last line becomes entirely empty because there was no previous element with which we could set it. Also note that I used empty strings as null elements, I did that because of the automatic type inference in pandas, which converts `None` to `np.nan` if column has float type.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been extremely helpful to me

Comment: @AlejandroMarín: If you are satisfied with this answer and consider the problem solved it would great if you could mark it as the solution to your question.

Comment: You're right, my bad, sorry, I just marked the +1. Thank you!